# How to display which repository SBT is getting package from?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, ivy

When I typed `sbt`, it displays the information below for very long time..

```
sbt
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.7 ...
```

But is there a way to show detailed information about (1) how sbt resolves dependencies and (2) which repository every package is downloading from? I tried `sbt -v` and `sbt --verbose` but neither works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To show resolved dependencies, there is an sbt plugin

https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

2. Which repository every package is downloading from

I'm not sure what do you need this information for. If dependency is not available in one repository sbt looks it up in another, until it finds it, or stops with unresolved dependency otherwise. So if you have dependency A in both repositories R1 & R2, source repository might change depending on R1 responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks.. I just want to know if I set a proxy repository, whether sbt tried that repository first before using public maven repository.. Is there a way to check this information?

Comment: Sometimes when my proxy repository doesn't work, it would be great if I could know whether the whole proxy repository is broken or just that dependency is not available in that repository..

Comment: @hanfeisun But if it fails, it shows all the tried repossitory right? For eg:           ==== releases: tried
[warn]   http://proxyurl/myjar_2.11/1.1.1.1/myjar_2.11-1.1.1.1.pom

Comment: Sbt tries repositories in order they are written. You can see used repo in sbt logs, so you can just clean your local repo, and track your logs.